# Simple example of using GWT editors with form validation?

Tags: java, gwt

I'm looking for a simple example of how to use GWT editor framework for editing a simple form. While there are examples out there, like [this](https://gist.github.com/tbroyer/780560), they emit any UI related parts, such as showing how everything fits together, how form validation errors could be displayed, etc.

Lets say I wanted to create a simple form for editing a Person, with textboxes for first name, last name, and email, and validation rules to make sure all fields were filled in, showing errors in case of validation errors. How can this be done with GWT editors?

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete example but have you looked at http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/editor/ui/client/ValueBoxEditorDecorator.html for showing the error?

I think we found it hard to extends so copy and pasted it, shame and us, and changed for our needs.

It is a nice pattern though, we also encapsulated the HTML for labels, mandatory indicators, help text etc in a similar way.

Comment: Any chance you could share some of your code and show an example of how you would show a simple form, validate it and show errors?

Comment: Hmmm. Is all work stuff so not in public repo I'm afraid. We also decided to heavily use @Valid which is tough to use with GWT RequestFactory. Sorry.

Comment: I understand, but you don't have to share any of your work code. Just a simple example with 2-3 form fields is all i need to get an idea..

Comment: How about the DynaTableRf sample? That is a complete example and has some validated fields on the PersonEditor...  I'm not sure we are using Editors/RequestFactory as intended so don't want to pass on our bad habits.